# Power BI - Registering an application and granting permission

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am stuck getting power bi embedded working.  I keep reading that I need to register an application in Azure/Power BI.

I have an existing web application.  Does that mean I can skip this step of creating one?  https://app.powerbi.com/embedsetup/AppOwnsData

note:  I'm trying to set this up with AppOwnsData, masteruser.

Is this where I add appropriate permisions if adding to an existing one?  [image]

and if I am adding permissions to this existing azure app, then does my user need permission to sign in to this particular app or just power bi?

Comment: Don't skip any of the steps.  It won't hurt anything to create a new application in AAD for your embedding.

Comment: but, which application needs the permissions?  The one that I register here in power bi embedded or my real one that I'm embedding it in?  Also, I'm embedding it all on front end app, so why would I need to give permissions to my back end app at all?

Comment: The one you register in the link.  It needs permissions to request the embedding token from the Power BI service.

Comment: so if I'm embedding entirely on front end, why do I need app permissions at all?

Comment: In the App-owns-data scenario, it's not "entirely on front end".  Your back-end application generates the embed token.

Comment: Are you saying the back end that is created via "register your app" (the link I posted in my question) is the back end that ACTUALLY GENERATES the token?  So Then in my front end, or postman, I can call generate token api?   so to reiterate, this has nothing to do with my current backend application that I have already running?    If yes, can you please post as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate an embedding token for Power BI your application code must first get an access token for Power BI, and to do this you must use the ApplicationId of an application registered in Azure Active Directory.

[Tutorial: Embed Power BI content using a sample embed for your customers'
application Step 2 - Register an Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core#step-2---register-an-azure-ad-application)

You can use an existing AAD Application, but the online wizard creates a new one for you with the appropriate permissions to create a new (additional) AAD App just for Power BI Authentication.

The required permissions are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-tokens#embed-for-your-customers), although you should at least test with the wizard-created application first.

Comment: Can you also point out where I can add appropriate permissions if using an existing aad application

Comment: see update to answer